# android read file from sd card

Tags: android, android-intent, readfile

I just need to covert the path in file to InputStream here is my code. I select the path by calling  Intent but it always gives me filenotfoundexception

```
       Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("*/*");
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);



       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)            {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), data.getData().toString());
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        File fpath=new File(path.toString());


        try {
            InputStream myfile=new FileInputStream(fpath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

thanks for help in advance...

Comment: `data.getData().toString()`. Have you logged that string? What is it's value?

Comment: `it always gives me filenotfoundexception`. Yes. And it also tells you which file it tried to find. Don't omit that. Tell us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();  
ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();              
try {
    InputStream myfile=cr.openInputStream(uri));;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity(). RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();


            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(filePath).asBitmap().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(avatarContainer);
                //avatarContainer.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                //uploadFile(filePath.getPath());


                try {
                    uploadFile(getPath(filePath));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Config.displayToast("Please Select Image From Gallary");
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    ServerRequest.dismissDialogBox(context);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == getActivity() .RESULT_OK){
              String filepath = fileUri.getPath();
              Log.d("Filepath is",""+filepath);

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
            //avatarContainer.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(filepath).asBitmap().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(avatarContainer);

            uploadFile(filepath);

        }
    }


    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```